# I was robbed. Can anything be done about this?

Tags: nft, phantom

I was robbed. I clicked on an unfamiliar nft in Phantom, went to some site where my wallet and the “log in” button were entered. I pressed login and the 1.8 Solana disappeared. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: Really sorry to hear that... you can go through legal channels and report it to Phantom, but otherwise there isn't too much that can be done unfortunately. If the scammer ever gets picked up by the authorities and they manage to seize the funds, maybe you'll get it back, but that's pretty rare.